# Loading an image file

Tags: python, image, numpy, computer-vision, anaconda

The task consists of the following :
"The input image is the set of 3 plates, corresponding to B, G, and R channels (top-down). You should implement the function   _   that reads the data and returns the list of images of plates.   _   is the path to the directory with plate images. If this directory is located in the same directory as this notebook, then default arguments can be used."

The file that contains images to load is plates. plates and the notebook are both in the same file called Deep Learning in Computer Vision.

This is the code I wrote:

```
def load_data(dir_name ='C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Self_Learning/Coursera/Deep Learning in Computer Vision/plates'):

    im_list=[]
    for i in dir_name:
        im=np.load(i)
        im_list.append(im)
    return im_list
    pass

plates = load_data()
```

This is the error I got.

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      8     pass
      9 
---> 10 plates = load_data()

in load_data(dir_name)
      3     im_list=[]
      4     for i in dir_name:
----> 5         im=np.load(i)
      6         im_list.append(im)
      7     return im_list

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    420         own_fid = False
    421     else:
--> 422         fid = open(os_fspath(file), "rb")
    423         own_fid = True
    424

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'

I tried this:

```
import os

def load_data(dir_name ='C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Self_Learning/Coursera/Deep Learning in Computer Vision/plates'):
    im_list=[]
    for f in os.listdir(dir_name):
        fpath = os.path.join(dir_name, f) # this will give you the path of each file in your directory
        for im in fpath:
            im_list.append(im)

    print(im_list)

plates = load_data()
```

but the result was not what I want:
[image]

what I want is ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
I basically ended up printing both the path of each image and the image...

Comment: Looks like you are iterating over `dir_name` which is a string

Comment: it's supposed to be the directory of the images (the file named plates that contains the images I need to load)

Answer (score 2):

This should give you what you want

```py
import os

def load_data(dir_name ='C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Self_Learning/Coursera/Deep Learning in Computer Vision/plates'):
    im_list=[]
    for f in os.listdir(dir_name):
        fpath = os.path.join(dir_name, f) # this will give you the path of each file in your directory
        do_something_with_your_file(fpath)
```

More info about `os.listdir()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

Also the `pass` statement after `return` has no effect.

Comment: is it possible to just stick with numpy?

Comment: You are using `numpy` to load the file and `listdir` to get the filenames in your directory, then `os.path.join` will give you the absolute path of the file (dirname + filename).

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating of the variable `dir_name` which is a string. The variable `i` is taking the value of a character in the string. You need to use the directory name to get the files in it, like bellow.

```
import os

def load_data(dir_name ='C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Self_Learning/Coursera/Deep Learning in Computer Vision/plates'):
  im_list=[]
  for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_name):
      for file in files:
         im=np.load(file)
         im_list.append(im)
  return im_list
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried this and it worked !

```
import os
import matplotlib.image as img

def load_data(dir_name ='C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Self_Learning/Coursera/Deep Learning in Computer Vision/plates'):
    im_list=[]
    for f in os.listdir(dir_name):
        fpath = os.path.join(dir_name, f) # this will give you the path of each file in your directory
        im = img.imread(fpath) 
        im_list.append(im)
    return im_list


plates = load_data()
```

Thanks for everyone's help.